# Getting no route matches on the show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to use the path from the following route, here is what it's like in `rake routes`

> chapter GET /chapters/:id(.:format) {:action=>"show", :controller=>"chapters"}

chapter_path creates a link to `/chapters/x` which is correct but I get the routing error when trying to access it.

> No route matches {:controller=>"chapters"}`

this is my routes (I am using shallow routing to create a `books_chapters` and `book_chapters_new` paths.

```
resources :books do
  resources :chapters, :shallow => true
end
```

when I test the route with rake routes, I get books_chapters, books_chapters_new, chapters and books, so I don't know what's wrong.

when i remove `:shallow => true`, i can access `/books/1/chapters/6` but I just want it to be `/chapters/6`

this is what my terminal looks like

[image: the routes should be working]

so `/chapters/id` and `/chapters/id/edit` should be working fine.

I've restarted the server with `touch tmp/restart.txt` and ran `rails s` to see if the routes worked there too and `rake routes` is giving me acceptable routes, but they don't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you supplying the parameter for the path helper, something like

```
chapter_path(@chapter)
```

Comment: yes, like this `<%= link_to chapter.title, chapter_path(chapter) %>` chapter is the iterator for the for loop in books index. the link created is /chapters/id which is what i want but that page is the issue, although `rake routes` is telling me `chapter_path()` is there.

Comment: might be a stupid question, but did you restart the server so that the routes can be picked up?

Comment: Can you go into your rails console and try `app.chapter_path(Chapter.first)`.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to get :shallow routes to work, and there isn't an example on how to use :shallow in the rails guide so, instead I have to just use nested routes like so

```
resources :books do
  resources :chapters
end
```

now this means the something like `chapters_url` or `chapters_path` won't work.

So I have to do something like this everywhere

```
book_chapter_url(@chapter.book, @chapter)
```

or

```
edit_book_chapter_path(@chapter.book, @chapter)
```

It works but there's a bit of code smell because I use @chapter twice and the whole url should be able to resolve just through the chapter id instead.